# Align multiple textboxes in a row react native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'm very much new to react native currently i'm building small app for just getting an idea about this. I'm facing an issue in aligning two textboxes and a button in a same row. Also i'm not much familiar with flex also. But i've tried using `flex-row` as the direction to align contents in a row and it succeeded but with a fixed width to the items. When i tried to use width as 100% design got breaked. This is what i tried yet. Also i'm using react-native-paper as the ui library.

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native'
import Background from '../components/Background'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import { Appbar, DataTable, Button } from 'react-native-paper'
import FlashMessage, { showMessage, hideMessage } from "react-native-flash-message";
import { theme } from '../core/theme'
import TextInput from '../components/TextInput'

const Dashboard = ({ navigation }) => {

  return (
    <Background>
      <Appbar style={styles.top}>
      <Appbar.Action
        icon="plus"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SaveDataScreen')}
      />
      <Appbar.Action
      style={styles.appbariconfloat}
        icon="power"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')}
      />
    </Appbar>
    <Header style={styles.headermargin}>Welcome back. </Header>
    <DataTable style={styles.datatable}>
      <DataTable.Header>
        <DataTable.Title>Dessert</DataTable.Title>
        <DataTable.Title numeric>Calories</DataTable.Title>
        <DataTable.Title numeric>Fat</DataTable.Title>
      </DataTable.Header>
      <ScrollView>
      <DataTable.Row>
        <DataTable.Cell>Frozen yogurt</DataTable.Cell>
        <DataTable.Cell numeric>159</DataTable.Cell>
        <DataTable.Cell numeric>6.0</DataTable.Cell>
      </DataTable.Row>
      </ScrollView>
    </DataTable>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <View style={{ width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue' }} >  
        <TextInput
          label="Password"
        />
        </View>
        <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue' }} >  
        <TextInput
          label="Password"
        />
        </View>
        <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue' }} >  
        <Button mode="contained">
          Login
        </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    <FlashMessage position="top" />
    </Background>
  )
}

export default Dashboard

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  top: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
  },
  headermargin: {
    marginTop: 40,
    fontSize: 21,
    color: theme.colors.primary,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    paddingVertical: 12,
  },
  card: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: 15,
    backgroundColor:'rgba(56, 172, 236, 1)',
    borderWidth:0,
  },
  customView: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: 37
  },
  appbariconfloat:{
    marginLeft: "auto",
  },
  datatable:{
    backgroundColor:'white'
  },
  
})
```

I need the design to be like this

[image]

This is the output for what i tried

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1, marginRight: 10, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>
        <TextInput label="Password" />
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 1, marginRight: 10, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>
        <TextInput label="Password" />
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 1, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>
        <Button mode="contained">Login</Button>
    </View>
</View>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. That is a CSS problem. Give some margins to button view.

```
      <View style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <View style={{ margin: 5, width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue' }} >  
        <TextInput
          label="Password"
        />
        </View>
        <View style={{ margin: 5, width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue' }} >  
        <TextInput
          label="Password"
        />
        </View>
        <View style={{ margin: 5, width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue' }} >  
        <Button mode="contained">
          Login
        </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Comment: I've tried this but this is what i'm not expecting i need the same width for three items in any screen size